# Sumifs for rows and columns that are in an interval

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula in excel that will take values from a table based on few criterias. Table looks like this:

```
+------------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+
| Month/Hour | 1  | 2  | 3  |  4  | 5  | 6  | 7  | 8  |
+------------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+
|          1 | 93 | 21 | 32 |  42 | 55 | 30 | 98 | 97 |
|          2 | 41 | 73 | 25 |  58 | 48 | 10 | 19 | 20 |
|          3 | 87 | 17 | 92 | 100 |  9 | 31 | 22 | 22 |
|          4 | 92 | 91 | 63 |  28 | 95 | 58 | 55 | 47 |
|          5 | 56 | 34 | 69 |  60 | 87 | 64 | 40 | 53 |
|          6 |  8 | 64 | 92 |  30 | 48 | 27 | 52 | 65 |
|          7 | 77 |  6 | 27 |  45 | 29 | 91 | 24 | 90 |
|          8 | 13 | 14 | 31 |  10 | 40 | 49 | 22 | 57 |
|          9 | 70 | 16 | 55 |  95 | 85 | 41 | 65 | 17 |
|         10 | 72 | 79 | 81 |  48 | 13 | 40 | 99 | 52 |
|         11 | 76 | 88 | 80 |  45 | 97 | 68 | 64 | 62 |
|         12 | 73 | 82 | 97 |  74 | 93 |  7 |  6 | 71 |
+------------+----+----+----+-----+----+----+----+----+
```

In the first column we have months (1 - January, 2 - February, etc.) In the first row we have hours from 1 to 8.

Now I need a formula that for months <3,8> would sum values from hours <2,6> and for the rest of months (1-2, 9-12) would sum values from hours <4,7>. I've tried using Sumifs formula but it seems like it works only for one column at a time.

If it is not viable to use formula then I have some VBA knowledge and such solution would be welcome too.

Comment: Instead of just down voting, you could just leave a comment why you are down voting. This is not very helpful.

Comment: Sumifs sums only one column depending on the values of multiple columns, so for instance sum up column D if the value in column A is 2 and value in column B is 5. I think you should give the combination of IF and SUM a try, which can sum up different columns depending on the if statement.

Comment: I've seen the solution when your criteria is based on matching a value. Then you can use sum and index functions. Unfortunately, in my case I have greater and lower than conditions at the same time and all things I've tried are not working. Thanks for your input anyway @Roosz0rd

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs ^^ here ^^. also [ask], [tour], and [mcve]. This question is a perfect example of everything that's wrong with the world. "I need XYZ, can someone please deliver it to me on a silver platter" is what it boils down to. This isn't what this site was made for.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I know what is wrong with this question, but Seidhe don't know :)

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs voting is meant to be anonymous.  And if you knew what was wrong and the reason for the downvotes, why did you not inform the OP of the issues instead of trying to call out the downvoters?

Comment: @ScottCraner ??

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry, I didn't even read your comment about the hypocrisy, I just upvoted Mat's Mug comments.

Comment: The thing is I've tried doing it myself before asking and I've even wrote that my Sumifs approach failed. I've also thought that by giving an example of a table and an example case (for months and hours) that I could later alter to my needs would be sufficient information for others. Seems I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming months are in `A2:A13` and the hours in `B1:I1` you can use this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A13,{3,8},0)*MATCH(B1:I1,{2,6},0))+0,B2:I13)`

Vary as required for any combination of months/hours

Answer (score 1):

list your months and hours then use MATCH inside an SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:I13,ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:I1,M:M,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A13,L:L,0)))
```

[image]

Neither the Months nor the Hours desired needs to be consecutive.

Comment: Or this mixture of mine and BarryHoudini's: `=SUMPRODUCT(B2:I13,--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:I1,M:M,0)*MATCH(A2:A13,L:L,0))))`

Comment: @barryhoudini finally got one that I did not overthink and is similar to yours.  My life is complete..... :)